# C++ and MQL4 Cannot find function in dll

Tags: c++, c, dll, struct, mql4

Alright, I know everyone is thinking, "This has already been answered several times."  Well, you are wrong.  This time is different.  I have tried all of those other answers.  So here is the situation.

I am creating an indicator in Metatrader 4 (mql4 code).  I am coding a dll to do the calculations in Visual Studio 2013 in C++.
The relevant `MQL4` **`#import`** code is:

```
#import  "test.dll"
bool  LiveChart( BarTrack &bars,
                 Stars    &points,
                 Patterns &gartleys[],
                 Patterns &bats[],
                 Patterns &butterflies[],
                 Patterns &cyphers[],
                 BarData  &rates[],
                 Basics   &basics
                 );
#import
```

and the call to the function in the **`OnCalculate()`** function:

```
     bool test = LiveChart( bars,
                            points,
                            gartleys,
                            bats,
                            butterflies,
                            cyphers,
                            rates,
                            basics
                            );
     Print( "test: ", test );
```

NOTE: All the passed arguments are **`struct`**-references. None of the structs contain objects, pointers, references, strings, other structs, classes, methods, or arrays.  Some of the structs are arrays, but that is entirely valid as a passed argument.  So, there are NO invalid arguments being passed.  I **have verified** that each `struct` passes successfully, on an individual basis.

Now the C++ code:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MT4_EXPFUNC __declspec(dllexport)

MT4_EXPFUNC bool __stdcall LiveChart(const BarTrack &bars, Stars &points, Patterns *gartleys, Patterns *bats,
Patterns *butterflies, Patterns *cyphers, const BarData *rates, Basics &basics)
{
   Observatory astronomer;

   return astronomer.OnCalculateLive(bars, points, gartleys, bats, butterflies, cyphers, rates, basics);
}
```

NOTE: I have also tried:

```
extern "C"
{
   MT4_EXPFUNC bool __stdcall LiveChart(const BarTrack &bars, Stars &points, Patterns *gartleys, Patterns *bats,
Patterns *butterflies, Patterns *cyphers, const BarData *rates, Basics &basics)
   {
      Observatory astronomer;

      return astronomer.OnCalculateLive(bars, points, gartleys, bats, butterflies, cyphers, rates, basics);
   }
}
```

In my def file:

```
LIBRARY test

EXPORTS
   LiveChart
```

I have reviewed the code with the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) program.  It tells me the name of the function is:

```
bool LiveChart(struct BarTrack const &,struct Stars &,struct Patterns *,struct Patterns *,struct Patterns *,struct Patterns *,struct BarData const *,struct Basics &)
```

As far as I understand, everything is as it should be.

**My question is**,

1. why does **<kbd>metatrader</kbd>** still say it cannot find the
   function name in the dll?
2. Have I overlooked something?
3. Am I using the wrong type of voodoo?
4. Are the stars not aligned properly?

Admittedly, I am still pretty new to C++ (about a month into it), but as far as can tell, everything is kosher, and it should work.

Comment: Did you try: extern __declspec(dllimport)  ?

Comment: When I enter that line of code, it gives me two error messages.  1:  "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier".  2: "expected a ';' ".

That said, I did try using the extern declaration as noted in the 4th code block.  And, the code is using the __declspec(dllimport) as noted in the 3rd code block.

Comment: I think your function should be inside a public class. So there is a way to be accesible outside on call. I don't know if you understand, but given a simple function call without even declare it as public should throws an error for no defined function call. Correct me if I am wrong. A bool, an int or whatever function you call, shoulld be make public. I think is I declare a generic int A function, it shall be called inside procedure not external (as your dll assumes). So public class, function return something. Call external class->function and see what I mean.

Comment: Well, I would try what you are suggesting, but...as far as all the examples, and tests, I have seen, and performed, the code I have should work exactly as is.  Which is why I finally gave up and posted it here.  I am hoping someone will have an idea of why metatrader would refuse a perfectly acceptable dll call.

Comment: And just to be clear....I have even copied the relevant code into a shell program and shell dll, for the purpose of testing, and they worked perfectly.  So, I honestly don't know why it rejects the call.  There is nothing that should interfere with it.

Comment: Last thing comes in my mind. Link .lib to compiler or #pragma comment(lib, "yourdll.lib")? Try to copy your dll in system folder? Check UAC permission?

Comment: Turned off UAC, added #pragma, etc..... no change.  It finds the dll, but still cannot find the function in the dll.  I checked the dll again with the Dependency Walker, and it still found the function exactly as It found in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Finally!  I have come to a resolution with this issue.  The issue was, the def file became unlinked to the project.  Here is what happened.

When starting a new dll project, VS creates a dllmain.cpp file with the main function in it.  I don't like having this extra file in the project, so I prefer to move the main function into my project.cpp file.  When I do this, I remove the dllmain.cpp file from the project.  Apparently, if you have already linked your def file before you remove the dllmain.cpp, it will unlink your def file.  I never even thought to recheck this because I knew I had already linked the def file correctly.

To fix the issue, all I had to do was select the project.cpp file, and go into the Project/Properties menu, and relink the def file.  Now, I can finally start debugging.....